# Email not sending to one particular domian

Tags: php, codeigniter

We are using amazon server and I am using PHP, Codeigniter framework.

Below is the script which I am using for sending emails.
It is working when I send an email to Gmail domain email id (abc@gmail.com) but it is not working on some specific domain name email id (abc@xyzdmainname.com).

```
  public function sendMail() {
  $to = 'abc@xyzdomain.com';
  $fromEmail = 'pqr@gmail.com';
  $fromName = 'pqr';
  $subject = 'Testing';
  $message = 'Testing of email';
  $newFile = ''
  $this->CI->load->library('email');
  $this->CI->email->mailtype = 'html';
  $this->CI->email->from($fromEmail, $fromName);
  $this->CI->email->to($to);
  $this->CI->email->subject($subject);
  $this->CI->email->message($message);
  if (!empty($newFile)) {
  $this->CI->email->attach($newFile);
  }
  $result = $this->CI->email->send();
  $message = '';
  if ($result) {
  return 1;
  } else {
  echo $this->CI->email->print_debugger();
  return 0;
  };
```

Please let me help what-what case may be here for fail sending email on a particular domain.

and How I can overcome this issue.

Comment: convet you to and from mail also string type in variable first and check it     $to = 'abc@xyzdomain.com'
 $fromEmail = 'pqr@gmail.com'

Comment: I have updated question, But actually, we are getting issue while sending an email on a perticular domain and on Gmail ids it's working fine.

Comment: try smtp mail it will help for sending mail.

Comment: I have tried with that also and a getting success even if I am passing wrong email id also, Please let me know if any way by which we can figure out that email id is wrong while sending an email.